# Destroying a Backbone Model in a Collection in one step?

Tags: collections, model, backbone.js

Are these two steps mandatory to delete a Model?

```
var model = collection.get(id);
model.destroy();
collection.remove(model);
```

Isn't there a way to destroy a model when it is removed from its collection?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Backbone you were using when you asked this question, but AFAIK at least in 0.5.3 when you call `.destroy()` on your model, Backbone removes it from the server and (provided that succeeded) then removes it from its collection automatically.

Comment: Nice. I was using version 0.3.3

Comment: Note for future readers: backbone will remove it from all collections, not just model.collection.  Collections listen to model events and 'destroy' causes a remove (with corresponding events).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
Model.bind("remove", function() {
  this.destroy();
});
...
var model = new Model();
...
collection.remove(model);
```

Removing a model from a collection triggers the `"remove"` event.

So if you want to, you can get models to bind to them and destroy themselves.

Comment: Thanks for this, however it's fairly unintuitive IMO. Is there any reason why you WOULDN'T want a model destroyed when calling remove on the collection (at least enough of a reason for this not to be the default behavior). Is this worth raising as a feature request on github?

Comment: @kissmyface Collections are arbitary (like in database terms) views over models. If I decide you shouldn't see Model X in View (collection) Y why would model X be destroyed?

Comment: That's a nice analogy. I didn't realize that they were quite so decoupled (all my code so far has had quite rigid links between collections and models). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @kissmyface however this doesn't mean we shouldn't have sugar like have with `.create` we could have a `.destroy` that destroys and removes a model on a collection

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I created a destroy method on my controller (takes a id as a param). Inside I destroy the model and then remove it from the collection - it works great.

Comment: I tried this, but `destory()` will invoke the `remove` event again, and `remove` event will invoke `destory()` again, so it ends up calling sync twice.  Is this expected?

Answer (score 1):

Calling collection.reset() without passing any models as arguments will empty the entire collection.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset