# Cleanest way to destroy every Model in a Collection in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

On the first attempt I wrote

```
this.collection.each(function(element){
    element.destroy();
});
```

This does not work, because it's similar to `ConcurrentModificationException` in Java where every other elements are removed.

I tried binding "remove" event at the model to destroy itself as suggested [Destroying a Backbone Model in a Collection in one step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280553/destroying-a-backbone-model-in-a-collection-in-one-step), but this will fire 2 delete requests if I call destroy on a model that belongs to a collection.

I looked at underscore doc and can't see a `each()` variant that loops backwards, which would solve the removing every element problem.

What would you suggest as the cleanest way to destroy a collection of models?

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could also use a good, ol'-fashioned <del>pop</del> destroy-in-place:

```
var model;

while (model = this.collection.first()) {
  model.destroy();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me `A "url" property or function must be specified` error. Changing `pop()` to `first()` or `last()` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, @david--that's a really good point! If the model URL is being inferred from the collection, removing the model will trigger this error. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Destroying a backbone model will trigger a DELETE api call - which throws the `A "url" property or function must be specified` error. You need to first `model.id = null` then you can `model.destroy()'

Answer (score 25):

I recently ran into this problem as well. It looks like you resolved it, but I think a more detailed explanation might also be useful for others that are wondering exactly why this is occurring.

### So what's really happening?

Suppose we have a collection (library) of models (books).

For example:

```
console.log(library.models); // [object, object, object, object]
```

Now, lets go through and delete all the books using your initial approach:

```
library.each(function(model) {
  model.destroy();
});
```

`each` is an underscore method that's [mixed into the Backbone collection](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-121). It uses the collections reference to its models (`library.models`) as a default argument for these various underscore collection methods. Okay, sure. That sounds reasonable.

Now, when model calls `destroy`, it [triggers a "destroy" event on the collection](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-120) as well, which will then [remove its reference to the model](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-88). Inside `remove`, you'll notice this:

```
this.models.splice(index, 1);
```

If you're not familiar with `splice`, see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). If you are, you can might see why this is problematic.

Just to demonstrate:

```
var list = [1,2];
list.splice(0,1); // list is now [2]
```

This will then cause the `each` loop to skip elements because the its reference to the model objects via `models` is being modified dynamically!

Now, if you're using JavaScript < 1.6 then you may run into this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined
```

This is because in the underscore implementation of `each`, it falls back on its own implementation if the native `forEach` is missing. It complains if you delete an element mid-iteration because it still tries to access non-existent elements.

If the native `forEach` did exist, then it would be used instead and you would not get an error at all!

Why? According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> If existing elements of the array are changed, or deleted, their value as passed to callback will be the value at the time forEach visits them; **elements that are deleted are not visited**.

So what's the solution?

Don't use `collection.each` if you're deleting models from the collection. Use a method that will allow you to work on a new array containing the references to the models. One way is to use the underscore [`clone` method](http://underscorejs.org/#clone).

```
_.each(_.clone(collection.models), function(model) {
  model.destroy();
});
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, thnx for the info

Comment: Thanks so much.  This was my first foray at messing with bbjs, and I decided to try to delete an entire collection piece-by-piece.  I was shocked to see a smattering of items removed each pass!  This explains what was happening superbly and removes some of the black magic from bbjs.

Answer (score 13):

I'm a bit late here, but I think this is a pretty succinct solution, too:

```
_.invoke(this.collection.toArray(), 'destroy');
```

Comment: Nice! We could even apply it to the collection directly: `this.collection.invoke('destroy');`

Comment: There was something about calling toArray that was important... but I don't remember a year later. :(

Comment: Quite possibly that collection iteration doesn't work gracefully if we're destroy elements as we go? Either way-- `toArray` is still a nice, tidy answer. If it works, let's go with that! :^)

Comment: I suspect you're correct. Invoke probably iterates over the elements and if you destroy it without creating a copy beforehand then the iteration will break, but not 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on Sean Anderson answer.
There is a direct access to backbone collection array, so you could do it like this.

```
_.invoke(this.collection.models, 'destroy');
```

Or just call `reset()` on the collection with no parameters, `destroy` metod on the models in that collection will bi triggered.

```
this.collection.reset();
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models

Answer (score 0):

This works, kind of surprised that I can't use underscore for this.

```
for (var i = this.collection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    this.collection.at(i).destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method, especially if you need to call destroy on each model, clear the collection, and not call the `DELETE` to the server.  Removing the `id` or whatever `idAttribute` is set to is what allows that.

```js
var myCollection = new Backbone.Collection();
var models = myCollection.remove(myCollection.models);
_.each(models, function(model) {
  model.set('id', null); // hack to ensure no DELETE is sent to server
  model.destroy();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need underscore and `for` loop for this.

```
this.collection.slice().forEach(element => element.destroy());
```