# Model.delete and Collection.delete with Backbone.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

Using Backbone.js with Express and MongoDB, I want to be able use Backbone's built-in REST capabilities, while also using query strings.

For example, if I delete a Backbone model, I want the route to go to

```
del /models/:model_id
```

however, I also want to be able to delete multiple items from the collection that uses that model, so that would be:

```
del /models?model_id=1&model_id=2&model_id=3
```

is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vanilla way is to call .destroy() for each of the models.  If you want to generate one event that deletes multiple specific models, you can over ride Backbone.Collection.sync or create a new function, but that's not the built in REST functionality.

[Cleanest way to destroy every Model in a Collection in Backbone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858935/cleanest-way-to-destroy-every-model-in-a-collection-in-backbone)

If your server route is fixed, you might implement a custom method to match it:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   url: '/models',
   initialize: function(options) { ...},
   deleteSelected: function(models, options) {
       var url = this.url;
       url += model_id='+models[0].id;
       for (var i=1; i<models.length; i++) url += '&model_id='+models[i].id;
       $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: url,
        success: options.success || function() {...},
        error: options.error || function() {...}
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks - I actually was asking if and how the structure of url:'models?model_id=' could be made compatible with backbones built-in REST capability

Comment: Backbone is really minimal.  On one hand it doesn't have a "delete some", so the vanilla route is just to delete them individually.  On the other, Backbone is just resolves to `$.ajax` anyways, so it's easy enough to define a route that makes sense.  Creating a route like you suggest can make sense if you want to make sure they all succeed or all rollback on failure.